# How to update a table based on an update from another table in oracle?

Tags: schema

I have a table T1 present in schema S1. Table T2 from schema S2. Both T1 and T2 have primary keys P1 and Q1.

I want to update T1 with updated Q1 from T2 for P1. I tried writing trigger which doesnot helped me as there is no privileges because S1 is application schema and S2 is product schema.

Please let me know the best solution to implement the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not Oracle's expert but I think that SQL Server have the same sintax:

```
UPDATE S1..T1
SET Field = TAB2.Field
FROM S1..T1 AS TAB1 INNER JOIN S2..T2 AS TAB2 ON TAB1.P1 = TAB2.Q1
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I have the update statement to do that. But my concern is I need to update the above statement in T1 dynamically based on the T2 update. Trigger on both the tables are not working because of access previlages.